# Code "broke" itself while uploading to BitBucket

Tags: git

Hello there and good morning,
So something weird happened to me yesterday at night. I was doing some of my final modifications on a **Laravel project** that I have and I was ready to push it to my **bitbucket**. After though the push, all my recently changed files had some extra lines added up to them.
Lines such as: `"<<<<<<< HEAD", "===================="`, and a random string that looked like a hash.

I attempted a google search about the `"<<<<<<< HEAD"` line, and I couldn't find anything related to my problem.

Here is some extra information about my **Environment**:

- I use **PhpStorm 10**
- My BitBucket is **private**, with only me being able to change it
- The BitBucket repo started as a clone of Laravel and then I did my changes.
- I use **SourceTree** to push/pull from the BitBucket Repo.

I am not really sure if it has anything to do with BitBucket, SourceTree or the generic structure of git. I do not really know also a lot of things about Git, only the basic stuff as push/pull/commit.

Could you please tell me about how to avoid something like this in the future?

Comment: I do not think that this has to do anything with bitbucket. Git server will not allow you to push if someone pushed before you lets say master branch. I think when you did pull you never solved conflicts.

Comment: @pregmatch I see... Now that you say this, i also noticed something weird. Even though this is a private repository i had to do a "pull" before anything. Again though, noone was in the repository, so how could someone else push in mine? Also, on the commits notes there was no history of any push by a different user, and i certainly did never add those lines.

Comment: can you post git log of your repository?

Comment: @pregmatch i am not really sure what exactly you need me to post. Do you need the contents of the code when the change happent?

Comment: @pregmatch or do you need something like that? http://prntscr.com/bl6ybx Oh, also, i don't know how it did the merge or even split up to different branches. I always publish it to master :/

Comment: You have made branch for this testing and then you did changes on same files on both branches. You pushed that branch and then when tyring to push master branch you were asked to pull first. And since you was working on both branches you master find same code on your test and then you did not solve that confilcts you just pushed.

Comment: I do not use gui for git so I see all my problems/conflicts before any push.

Comment: @pregmatch I think i get the idea. I guess i will have too look an indepth tutorial about git and/or bitbucket for its logic as well as a guide for SourceTree. Thank you, your information was very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens if git decides that you need to merge work - this typically happen if you commit from more than one computer, and you forget to pull old workd before you commit new work - and you choose to do it by fixing the file manually.  The `>>>>>`, `=====` and `<<<<<<` indicate where the snippet in question came from.

You need to clean up the file manually and commit it locally, to remove the "merging needed flag".

You can also do a `git reset --hard` to revert to the state before the pull, and try again.  If you - or git - get completely confused, create a new clone and do the work you did locally again in that and *then* commit the new work.